# IPy taking absurdly long to load imports

Tags: python, ipython

The following block of code

```
%matplotlib inline
import sys
import pandas as pd
sys.path.append("C:\Users\%USER%\PycharmProjects\cap_rate")
import mongo
import c_lib
import t_lib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

Is taking upwards of ten minutes to run.

Does anyone have an idea as to what may be the root cause of this?

No major warnings/output on my end outside of severe slowness.

Comment: it seems my personal imports are taking exceptionally long. any input as to what could lead to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted and it is much faster.